# Unity3D iOS export error - No matching function for call to 'objc_msgSendSuper'

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I tried to export my Unity3D project for iOS, but I keep getting this error:

```
No matching function for call to 'objc_msgSendSuper'

[DIRECTORY]/Classes/UI/UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm:166:5: No matching function for call to 'objc_msgSendSuper'

[DIRECTORY]/Classes/UI/UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm:180:5: No matching function for call to 'objc_msgSendSuper'

[DIRECTORY]/Classes/UI/UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm:210:5: No matching function for call to 'objc_msgSendSuper'
```

I also get the following hints:

```
[DIRECTORY]/Classes/Unity/ObjCRuntime.h:20:43: Expanded from macro 'UNITY_OBJC_FORWARD_TO_SUPER'

[DIRECTORY]/Classes/Unity/ObjCRuntime.h:11:60: Expanded from macro 'UNITY_OBJC_SEND_MSG'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/usr/include/objc/message.h:65:1: Candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were provided
```

XCode marks the following lines of code:

```
UNITY_OBJC_FORWARD_TO_SUPER(self_, [UIViewController class], @selector(willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:), WillRotateToInterfaceOrientationSendFunc, toInterfaceOrientation, duration);
```

and

```
UNITY_OBJC_FORWARD_TO_SUPER(self_, [UIViewController class], @selector(didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:), DidRotateFromInterfaceOrientationSendFunc, fromInterfaceOrientation);
```

and

```
UNITY_OBJC_FORWARD_TO_SUPER(self_, [UIViewController class], @selector(viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:), ViewWillTransitionToSizeSendFunc, size, coordinator);
```

I've tested to build the app on a simulated iPhone X (iOS 11.4).

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

MacOS: HighSierra 10.13.4
Unity3D (Personal): 2018.1.1f1
XCode: 9.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same issue on Unity 2018.1.3

Managed to compile and run on simulator after turning off "Enable Strict Checking of objc_msgSendCalls" option (Under Project -> Apple LLVM 9.0 Preprocessing).

I don't know much about native iOS developement, so this might be horrible to just ignore such errors. I'm trying to downgrade to Unity 2017.3.1 where I didn't have 
these errors.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Thanks for the tip! The app works well, so I guess this option isn't that important.

Comment: Didn't work for me, instead of that error it return so much errors "Apple Mach-O Linker Error", any help with that please?

Comment: @hoby are you using EasyAR or any other third party service? For me it helped to read the Apple export notes from EasyAR, because they mentioned a few values that needed to be changed before exporting it.

Comment: @Mario yes I missed Vuforia library, after attaching it the problem is solved finally, thank you sir (Y)

Comment: @hoby glad that you've found the problem :-)

Comment: How do you get to the LLVM processing settings? I have scoured through XCode and Unity project, but I cannot seem to find it. @hoby